# Генераторы случайных чисел XORShift и на основе Метода Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, c, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Вопрос такой, как генерировать вещественные числа в определенном диапазоне [0;1] с помощью `XORShift` и генератора на основе Метода Фибоначчи с запаздываниями, и возможно ли это?

Я имею в виду, как этими генераторами пользоваться, чтобы получить число в нужном мне интервале? В интернете мало информации на русском языке, даются только сами алгоритмы.

Вот например функция `rand()` стандартной библиотеки `С/C++` генерирует числа в диапазоне от `0` до `RAND_MAX`. И для получения вещественных чисел в определенном диапазоне мне нужно записать

```
double x = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * ((max) - (min)) + (min)`
```

где `min` - это начало диапазона, а `max` - конец,например 0 и 1.

Так вот, как быть с `XORShift` и генератором Фибоначчи?

Код для XORShift генератора :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

unsigned int  x = 548787455, y = 842502087, z = 3579807591, w = 273326509;
static unsigned int XORShift() {
    unsigned int t = x ^ (x << 11);
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
}
int main()
{
    const int N = 100;
    long double* Array = new long double[N];
    for (int i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        long double x = (long double)XORShift() / (long double)4294967295 * ((1) - (0)) + (0);
            Array[i] = x;
        cout << Array[i] << endl;
    }   
    system("PAUSE");
    delete[] Array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У Вас хотя бы генератор на основе Метода Фибоначчи с запаздываниями уже реализован? Или всё дело в том, что его пока ещё у Вас нет?

Comment: @RomanPodymov да,алгоритм есть.Проблема в том,что я не совсем понимаю в каком диапазоне он генерирует числа.То есть вводятся 2 числа (или лаги) и на их основе рандомятся значения.Мне это мало что дает на самом деле.В добавок ко всему, они целые без знаковые,мне же нужны вещественные в диапазоне от 0 до 1.

Comment: @RomanPodymov а что насчет XORShift генератора,вы знаете как управлять диапазоном ?

Comment: Вам уже ответили по этому поводу, изучите внимательно ответ.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Я не знаю в каком диапазоне возвращаются значения,в интернете об этом нет ни слова,ибо это не стандартная функция,а метод на основе которого можно рандомить числа.Решил задать вопрос здесь чтобы подсказали,как это реализовать,видимо напрасно.

Comment: Что значит Вам неизвестен диапазон возвращаемых значений? Если функция не Ваша, то изучите её код, тогда Вам станет понятно, какие она может значения генерировать.

Comment: @RomanPodymov я прикреплю алгоритм,для наглядности.Там используются побитовые сдвиги десятизначных чисел,как я вообще должен это понять ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без разницы, любой генератор дает псевдослучайные числа в диапазоне от, скажем, [image: введите сюда описание изображения] до [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Вам нужно получить из генерируемых чисел *g* значения в диапазоне от [image: введите сюда описание изображения] до [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Тогда просто для данного *g* вычисляйте значение из уравнения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вычислений нужно подобрать соответствующие типы и арифметические операции, чтоб избежать всяческих неприятностей типа переполнений или потерь точности, но принцип остается...

*"По-моему, так"* (с) Пух

Comment: А как это все на практике реализовать,в условиях языка c/c++?

Comment: Что именно? Четыре арифметических действия, или реализовать генераторы?

Comment: Сами генераторы.Как я написал выше,проблема в том,что я не знаю в каком диапазоне возвращаются значения.В интернете об этом нет ни слова,ибо это не стандартная функция,а метод на основе которого можно рандомить.То есть , я могу взять оттуда алгоритм,но ведь не знаю в каком интервале хотел работать автор,и соответственно ваше уравнения применить не смогу.

Comment: Ну так так и надо спрашивать :) XORshift просто очевиден - от 0 до 0xFFFFFFFF - понятно, на 32 разрядах. Фибоначчиев - откровенно говоря, я с ним незнаком, искать читать теорию некогда, но раз у вас есть реализация - ну просто погоняйте его и посмотрите, какие он даст максимальное и минимальные значения, если не хотите почитать. XORshift просто из вашего исходника очевиден.

Comment: Так если диапазон очевиден,и он всегда один и тот же,для чего же используются эти "магические числа" в самой первой строке.Они ведь могут быть разными?

Comment: Чтобы значения были разнообразные :) Можно взять какие-то числа и получить цикл из небольшого количества значений. Обычно выбор параметров ГСЧ - еще та работенка...

Comment: Ну я вроде бы немного разобрался,осталась пара вопросов.1)При выборке в 10000 элементов получается так :max  4294466230
min  1278671.Не очень то это похоже на диапазон от 0 до 0xFFFFFFFF.2)Возможно ли узнать универсальный диапазон, и выбрать в качестве параметров,например, время?

Comment: 10000 - это не проверка :) Например, в цикле до 0x0FFFFFFF - это 0x11 и 0xFFFFFFF0 - куда ближе. Теоретически - есть алгоритмы для поиска циклов в таких последовательностях, это самое надежное. Чтобы ответить на ваш второй вопрос - надо быть математиком высокого уровня; я, увы, таким не являюсь...

Comment: @ Harry Спасибо,за все.Я уже окончательно разобрался.Эти генераторы вообще странная штука.Если я,например,захочу получить другую выборку чисел,придется половину кода переписывать.Кстати, для рандома чисел в нужном диапазоне мне нужно использовать rand_max.Без предварительной прогонки дополнительного массива никак не удастся его узнать ?

Comment: Обычно тот, кто пишет генератор, описывает и все его свойства :) Старый стандартный генератор `rand()` генерирует значения от 0 до `RAND_MAX`. Сейчас в стандарт C++ натыкали столько всяких генераторов и распределений,что в них запутаться можно, так что смысла писать своё особого нет.

Comment: Да у меня задание такое. Сравнить генераторы случайных чисел:стандартный rand(),XORShift,генератор на основе метода Фибоначчи.Вот я и думаю как наиболее лаконично все это реализовать.

Comment: А... Ну, я бы написал какой-то код для проверки свойств ГСЧ, принимающий функцию генератора как параметр, ну, и соответственно, функции генерации. Ну, а что там должен проверять код, какие статистические характеристики - это уже вам видней.

Comment: Да я думаю разберусь.Спасибо еще раз